# Update XML data type without creating duplicate nodes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

In my application, users can select groups of skills to search, which are stored as XML.  In this simple example, I have the following structure in a table with a primary XML index included.

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, userId int NOT NULL, searchXml xml not null);
GO
CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX [Ix1] ON #myTable (searchXml) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
INSERT INTO #myTable (userId, searchXml) VALUES 
    (1, '<search><skills><s id="4" /><s id="10" /></skills></search>'),
    (1, '<search><skills><s id="4" /><s id="8" /><s id="10" /></skills></search>'),
    (2, '<search><skills><s id="7" /><s id="8" /><s id="10" /></skills></search>'),
    (3, '<search><skills><s id="4" /><s id="10" /><s id="11" /></skills></search>');
SELECT * FROM #myTable;


DROP TABLE #myTable;
GO
```

I need to perform the following update, but after some lengthy reading up cannot get anything even close:

Skill ID 4 is to be combined with Skill ID 8, leaving only Skill ID 8.
Therefore, each piece of XML data needs to be updated in the following manner:

1. If 4 & 8 exist in the same XML, remove 4, leaving only 8
2. If 4 exists in isolation, then change 4 to 8
3. If 8 exists in isolation, take no action

Can anyone help me improve my XML skills by sharing a solution?

Comment: do you need to do it with one query or can it be with multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it with two updates:

> 1. If 4 & 8 exist in the same XML, remove 4, leaving only 8

```
UPDATE #myTable
SET searchXml.modify('
delete (/search/skills[data(s/@id)=4 and data(s/@id)=8]/s[@id=4])')
```

and if only one occurence of `<s id="4"/>` is allowed per skills element and only one skills element per search and only one search element:

> 2. If 4 exists in isolation, then change 4 to 8

```
UPDATE #myTable
SET searchXml.modify('
replace value of 
(/search/skills[data(s/@id)=4 and not(data(s/@id)=8)]/s[@id=4]/@id)[1] 
 with 8 ')
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you.  Could you please explain what this bit means `data(s/@id)=8]/s[@id=4])`, with reference to the `/`?  Also, in the second part, `<s id="4"/>` *may* exist twice if the XML hasn't been created properly (outside our control), so we'd want to update all `4`'s into `8`

Comment: `skills[data(s/@id)=4 and not(data(s/@id)=8)]` means filter skills that have at least one element s with an attribute with value 4 and do not have any elements with an attribute 8. If multiple `<s id="4" />` exist you should use a `delete (/search/skills/s[@id=4 and position()>1])` in order to delete the extra appearances as replace cannot replace multiple nodes at once.